# CD/DVD-drive scan noise upon inserting/removing USB or headphones

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting

Ever since I updated to Windows 10, my CD/DVD-drive makes a beep sound, as if it is checking to see if a dvd or cd is inserted, whenever I insert/remove my headphones or a USB device into my pc. Is this intended or caused by something else?

Comment: Could you please include the manufacturer and model number of you CD/DVD Drive? Also, does this noise persist when there is no CD/DVD in the drive?

Comment: I have a Dell Latitude E5540 and the dvd-drive is listed as PLDS DVD+-RW DU-8A5HH. The noise is there even when there is no disc in the drive.